# How do market makers calculate bid/ask prices to quote for RFQs, specifically for stocks?

Tags: equities, pricing, market-making

Say a client submits an RFQ to buy/sell 100,000 Apple shares. The market maker will respond with their bid/ask prices.

My question is how are these bid/ask prices calculated by the market maker? Is the quoted price as simple as current price of 1 Apple share plus/minus some bid/ask spread %?

Comment: Not exactly, as it doesn't tell me how the price is set.

Comment: What exactly is missing? centerforfinancialstability.org/amfm_data.php?startc=2004&startt=2005 offers more a more in depth explanation.